# why does "float" in css ruin the background color

Tags: css

When I use this, then the background-color works

```
    header {
        background-color: #bab615;

    }
    nav {
        background: #f96e5b;
        width: auto;
    }
    nav ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        line-height: 1;
        display: block;
        zoom: 1;
    }
```

but if I add a float to "nav ul" e.g. float: left; then it makes the background color of both elements white... Why?

```
     header {
        background-color: #bab615;

    }
    nav {
        background: #f96e5b;
        width: auto;
    }
    nav ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        line-height: 1;
        display: block;
        zoom: 1;
        float: left; <---This
    }
```

Edit: changed #cssmenu to nav, since it is a nav in the html
Edit#2: jsfiddle.net/5vjor56y

Comment: try to add clear: both; to #cssmenu. A jsfiddle example from your html/css code would be helpful.

Comment: Could you put this CSS code in an online example together with a basic HTML?

Comment: Sure http://jsfiddle.net/5vjor56y/ I have commented the float in the css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need to clear the floated elements within `nav`.

You can do this within the css like so:

```
nav {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

This is where the "clearfix" comes into play. It's another way to do the above:

```
.nav:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

The clearfix is probably the best way to do this, as you don't need to create html elements whose sole purpose is to clear floated elements. For a deeper understanding of why this must be done, see this [css tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/).

Comment: Oops, excuse the duplicated links/content that @Set Sail Media posted.

Comment: Here's a detailed article, from CSS Tricks as well, about the clear fix – https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear floats.

`<div style="clear:both;"></div>`

or

`<br clear="all" />`

are two common ways. This should be placed immediately following the closing tag of the floated element(s), i.e.:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div style="clear:both;">
</nav>
```

Comment: It worked.. :) 

Can you explain why I need to clear floats?

Comment: When you float something, you're disrupting the natural flow of the elements on the page. They don't add height to the parent (container) element. In order to restore height (and thus background and other properties) you need to clear. There's several good articles out there, this does a pretty good job of explaining: https://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/

Answer (score -1):

Just simply put overflow as hidden on the parent element. It will work for you.

```
overflow:hidden;
```